# Get time stamp on a automatic saved text file

Tags: python, time

I'm currently running some simulations in a python program. When the simulation is done it writes out a text file with some data. Unfortunately, the way this is done is saving the text in the same folder, and with the same name. These are also time consuming simulations, that uses one core of my CPU at the time, which means I can do multiple simulations at a time.

But this also means, that when if I do this, and walk away, and don't come back in time, there will be some overwriting - which is not what I want :)

So my question is (I'm not very good at Python): Can I put a time stamp or something in the end, that would make every file unique somehow, unless they are done at the exact same time ? :)

The code I'm using for creating the text file is:

```
np.savetxt('/home/user/Desktop/DVH/dvh-%s.txt'%(name.replace("/","-")), dvh1, delimiter=',')
```

Don't know if any other info is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: `os.getpid()` can be useful for this. Or give it a 'job id' on the command line and put that in the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime` library, taking the current time with the `now` function and formatting it with the `strftime` function.

```
import datetime

time_str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
file_name_format = '/home/user/Desktop/DVH/dvh-%s_%s.txt'
file_name = file_name_format%(name.replace("/","-"), time_str)
np.savetxt(file_name, dvh1, delimiter=',')
```